# DNS not resolving for some ISPs

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm working with an organization that is having trouble with its DNS server. They're running an old CentOS install with an old Bind 9. They're hosting their own DNS, but some queries are failing. I think I've narrowed the problem down a little bit: queries against non-recursive DNS servers are failing.

Here's a recursive query against Google's public DNS:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 vancouverpride.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 vancouverpride.ca
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28197
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vancouverpride.ca.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vancouverpride.ca.  14398   IN  A   66.84.14.159

;; Query time: 1096 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul  8 14:54:11 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

When I run the same query against a Telus DNS (while connected to the Telus ISP), I get an error:

```
$ dig @209.115.152.130 vancouverpride.ca

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @209.115.152.130 vancouverpride.ca
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 51444
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vancouverpride.ca.     IN  A

;; Query time: 50 msec
;; SERVER: 209.115.152.130#53(209.115.152.130)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul  8 14:59:14 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

So Telus ISP subscribers aren't able to access the site but everyone else is.

I'm over my head with this DNS stuff, so any help is appreciated. This system was set up several years ago, and isn't documented.

So far, I've tried the diagnostic tools at whatsmydns.net, which reports one problem with DNS A records propagation in India.

Comment: Are you sure the Telus DNS servers you're using are actually Telus DNS servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of your nameservers do not resolve.

Delegatory `NS` records and glue `A` records (from the `ca` nameservers) look like the following:

```
vancouverpride.ca.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.vancouverpride.ca.
vancouverpride.ca.      86400   IN  NS  ns2.vancouverpride.ca.
ns1.vancouverpride.ca.  86400   IN  A   66.84.14.159
ns2.vancouverpride.ca.  86400   IN  A   66.84.14.160
```

However, when querying `66.84.14.159` or `66.84.14.160` for `ns1.vancouverpride.ca` or `ns2.vancouverpride.ca` they respond with `NXDOMAIN`.

This working at all, at least in some cases, comes down to just using the glue data without having looked up the authoritative records.

Comment: So I should add the entries for ns1.vancouverpride.ca. and ns2.vancouverpride.ca. ?

Comment: @Michael Either add `A` records for these names or adjust the delegation to refer to other names that do exist.